# Why does watching a gif on Twitter change my music player volume? (Firefox/PulseAudio)

Tags: audio, alsa, pulseaudio

Strange question, but this has been bugging me for a long time now. Sometimes when I scroll through my Twitter feed in Firefox, if a gif automatically plays (in a `<video>` element, so probably .gifv), the output of Quod Libet (or Spotify) seems to get halved. I've noticed this only happens if Quod Libet isn't set to 100% in `pavucontrol`. When I play a gif, no volume sliders actually move. Both Quod Libet and FireFox show up as "ALSA Plugin", so there is a chance this is a problem with ALSA.

Either way, Google is giving me nothing helpful, other than suggesting I disable `flat-volume`, but that sounds more about the device output level actually changing - which is not what I'm seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I set `flat-volumes = no` (as documented in [`pulse-daemon.conf`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/pulse-daemon.conf)) and it seems that might well have been it. What a confusing option!

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution, but could you please edit and clarify how exactly this setting is changed? What file did you edit? What GUI tool did you use?

Comment: Worked for me too.  I copied /etc/pulse/daemon.conf  to $HOME/.pulse/daemon.conf and comment this point out.